# Absolute positioning of Python tkinter elements

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make tkinter elements with absolute positioning so they don't push each other?

Comment: I think with the edit, and considering the potentially useful answer, we can leave this question open. _Someone_ was able to answer it meaningfully.

Comment: I really don't understand why this question was closed, since it has a very clear and distinct answer - the `place()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell what exactly you are looking for. If so far you've only used the `pack()` method for your layout, you should use `grid()`. Personally, I think `grid()` is flexible enough for most layouts, while at the same time being somewhat *sane*, i.e., preventing elements from overlapping each other.

If this is still too restrictive for your purposes, and you really want to position elements by their *(x, y)* coordinates, you can use the `place()` method.

Here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/layout/), explaining the several layout management methods for Tkinter in detail, starting with absolute layout.